# Flutter / Issues with widget placement - getting white screen for Text forms

Tags: flutter, dart

I having an issue with hierarchy of the element as atm getting white screen if i access "Add Book" window, but not text fields just blank page. **I do get these errors:**

1. NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
2. RenderRepaintBoundary#5e192 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT Failed
3. assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
4. [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.

Maybe someone could explain what mistakes i'm doing to understand it better. Thank you in advance!

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Add book")),
      body: Container(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                // Book name

                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Container(
                    //height: 30,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    ),
                    //alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0x70487bea),
                          borderRadius:
                              new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: nameController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: " Write name",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // Author
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    ),
                    //alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0x70487bea),
                          borderRadius:
                              new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: authorController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: " Write name",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // Category
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                    value: dropdownValue,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Choose category",
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    //alignment: Alignment.center,
                    items: listOfCategories.map((String value) {
                      return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: new Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        dropdownValue = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),

                //temp placement
                // Submit
                Flexible(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: isLoading
                        ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                        : Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    isLoading = true;
                                  });
                                  //getUsername();
                                  addToFb();
                                  //dispose();
                                }
                              },
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.indigo[500])),
                              color: Colors.indigo[400],
                              child: Text(
                                "Save",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35, 15, 35, 15),
                            ),
                     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
(Put your widgets in the `Column` under the `Form`)

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:
                Text("Add book"),
              ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(...),
               ),
            ),
),
```

Comment: Hvala. Now it shows the name of the window, but it doesn't load text forms. I do get this new error [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.

Comment: I have tried, now i have full white windows and unable to go with  'Navigator' to main page    //                                                                                                                                  Main repeating errors: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderSingleChildViewport#fc53f relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'